# Converse to Vitali's Convergence Theorem for a subset of the sigma algebra.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The converse to Vitali's Convergence theorem, in part, states the following. Given a measure space $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$, suppose that there is a sequence of real-valued $\mu$-measurable functions $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ for which the limit $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_Af_n\ d\mu$ is finite for every $A\in\mathcal{A}$. Then, there is an integrable function $g$ for which
\begin{equation}
\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_A f_n\ d\mu=\int_Ag\ d\mu \hspace{1in}  (1)
\end{equation}
for every $A\in\mathcal{A}$.

Here is my question. The requirement that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_Af_n\ d\mu$ be finite for every $A\in\mathcal{A}$ may be difficult to establish sometimes. If $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_Af_n\ d\mu$ is finite for each set $A$ in some subset $\mathcal{S}$ of $\mathcal{A}$, will there still exist an integrable function $g$ for which
(1) holds for every set $A\in\mathcal{S}$ ? If this is not the case for every arbitrary subset of $\mathcal{A}$, is there some setting in which this is the case where $\mathcal{S}$ is a strict subset of $\mathcal{A}$?

In particular, consider the measure space $(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathcal{B}_n, \lambda_n)$  where $\mathcal{B}_n$ is the Borel algebra on $\mathbb{R}^n$ generated by the open sets (with the usual topology), and $\lambda_n$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose that $\mathcal{S}$ is the collection of all rectangles in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Will (1) hold for every rectangle $A\in\mathcal{S}$ ?

Comment: If each $f_n$ is just assumed to be measurable, some integrals $\int_Af_nd\mu$ might be undefined. At first glance, I might suggest that adding that $f_n\geq 0$ or $f_n \in L^1$ for all $n$ would get rid of bad behaviour in the sequence.